# Middle inverse matrix in between 2 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, inverse

Middle inverse. Suppose ***A*** is an ***n×p*** matrix and ***B*** is a ***q×n*** matrix. If a ***p×q*** matrix ***X*** exists that satisfies ***AXB = I***, we call it a middle inverse of the pair ***A, B***. (This is not a standard concept.) Note that when ***A*** or ***B*** is an identity matrix, the middle inverse reduces to the right or left inverse, respectively.

(a) Describe the conditions on ***A*** and ***B*** under which a middle inverse ***X*** exists. Give your answer using only the following four concepts: Linear independence of the rows or columns of ***A***, and linear independence of the rows or columns of ***B***. You must justify your answer.

(b) Give an expression for a middle inverse, assuming the conditions in part (a) hold.

**My attempt for part A:**

(a) In order for X to exist, A and B have to be the non-zero matrix. The rows of A must be linearly independent and the columns of B must be linearly independent.

Reasons:

***AXB = I***  so ***A(XB) = I***, so ***XB*** will be the right inverse of ***A***, so the rows of A are linearly independent.

***AXB = I***  so ***(AX)B = I***, so ***AX*** will be the left inverse of ***B***, so the columns of B are linearly independent.

Comment: not sure if my answer for part A is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a)

In order for X to exist, A and B have to be the non-zero matrix.

***AXB = I***  so ***A(XB) = I***, so ***XB*** will be the right inverse of ***A***, so the rows of A are linearly independent.

***AXB = I***  so ***(AX)B = I***, so ***AX*** will be the left inverse of ***B***, so the columns of B are linearly independent.

(b)

A has a right inverse, so $AA^* = I$

B has a left inverse, so $B^*B = I$

so

$AXB=I$

$AA^*B^*B = I$

$X = A^*B^*$

By Pseudo Inverse:

$A^* = A^T(AA^T)^{-1}$

$B^* = (B^TB)^{-1}B^T$

so

$X = A^*B^* = A^T(AA^T)^{-1}(B^TB)^{-1}B^T $